# Can JasperReports include a pdf in a report?

Tags: pdf-generation, jasper-reports, itext

Is it possible to include an existing pdf file in a JasperReport?

We really want to append new data to an existing report with out regenerating the existing report.  We will be exporting back to pdf.  I'm looking at using iText's PdfCopy to merge two pdfs, but was hoping JasperReports might have an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could do that in JasperReports, but it would be fairly simple in [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/).

Generate the JasperReport, and then use [PdfCopy](http://www.1t3xt.info/api/index.html?com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html) to append the new report to the original (or vice-versa).