# How to include a pdf into a jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I was curious if there is a way to include a static pdf in the middle of a jasper report. The jasper report will have a static pdf and that pdf will be included in the pdf that is created by the report. For example, the pdf exists of 3 pages, and in the final pdf that has been created by jasper, page 1-2 is created by jasper, 3-4 is the static pdf and 5-6 is again created by jasper. What I am asking is how to include a pdf in the middle of a jasper report instead of at the end. Is there a way to achieve that?

Edit: I can maybe use iText to do it, but my business requirement is to do this using jasper reports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JasperReports include a pdf in a report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935802/can-jasperreports-include-a-pdf-in-a-report)

Comment: @AlexK Nope. That question is about how to append the pdf after the jasper report. This is about how to include the pdf in the middle of the jasper report.

Comment: It is the same function :)

Comment: @AlexK Are you referring to iText? That link is broken

Comment: You can also try to build your custom component for showing pdf with help of Generic component

Comment: `Are you referring to iText?`  - Yes (but not me, the author of the answer)

Comment: @AlexK "You can also try to build your custom component for showing pdf with help of Generic component" Do you have an example of that? I don't think iText is an option here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138267/discussion-between-browntowncoder-and-alex-k).

Comment: iText documentation: [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly) & [Chapter 6: Working with existing PDFs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6)